# The set of inner products of two compact sets compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Is the following statement true? Below is my proof. Is my proof correct?

*Suppose $x\in X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $y\in Y\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $X,Y$ are compact. Then, the set $\langle X,Y\rangle=\{\langle x,y\rangle \in \mathbb{R} \mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$ is compact.*

Proof:
Since, in finite dimension, compactness is equivalent to being closed and bounded, I will show as such.

**Boundedness**: Suppose $|x|\leq M_x,\forall x\in X$ and $|y|\leq M_y,\forall y\in Y$. Then, for any arbitrary element of $\langle x,y\rangle\in\langle X,Y\rangle$, Cauchy Schwarz's inequality yields $|\langle x,y \rangle|\leq |x||y|\leq M_xM_y$.

**Closedness**: (This is a cop out from what I saw about Cartesian Product on MSE but I don't see why the same argument cannot be applied here. So here it is.) Since $X,Y$ are closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $X^c,Y^c$ are open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus $\langle X^c, \mathbb{R}^n\rangle \bigcup \langle \mathbb{R}^n, Y^c\rangle$ is open. But $\langle X,Y\rangle^c=\langle X^c, \mathbb{R}^n\rangle \bigcup \langle \mathbb{R}^n, Y^c\rangle$. Thus, $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is closed.

Comment: Continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: @geetha290km It took me a while to see what you are saying. Let me make sure I understand you correctly. The inner product is bounded so it is continuous. Therefore, I can take any open cover of $\langle X,Y\rangle$ and preimages will be open and they will cover $X$ and $Y$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are compact, there is a finite cover. Now the corresponding images of that finite cover will cover $\langle X,Y\rangle$. Therefore, $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is compact. Am I quoting you correctly?

Comment: What was most likely being stated is the following: The mapping $(x,y)\mapsto \langle x, y\rangle$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. As $X$ and $Y$ are compact in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $X\times Y$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}$. So as $\langle X, Y\rangle$ is the image of the continuous mapping under the compact set $X\times Y$, it follows that $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Now you need a few results to show that statement above, some of which are the following:
- The product of two compact subsets is compact in the product of the underlying metric (or topological) spaces.
- The mapping $(x,y)\mapsto \langle x, y\rangle$ is continuous.
If you struggle to show those results, what you can instead do to obtain your desired result is to use that a set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact if it is sequentially compact, which means that every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: And regarding your proof, the boundedness part is correct. But it is not true that $\langle X, Y\rangle^{c} = \langle X^{c}, \mathbb{R}^{n}\rangle \cup \langle \mathbb{R}^{n}, Y^{c}\rangle$. So you need another approach to show that the set is closed.

Comment: @Dean Miller Wow! Your comments help so much. Thanks a lot. There are a few details I was taking for granted - for example, showing the product of two compact subsets is compact in the product of two underlying metric spaces. Would you write it up as the answer and post it? Could you kindly explain why $\langle X,Y\rangle^c\neq \langle X^c,\mathbb{R}^n\rangle\bigcup \langle\mathbb{R}^n,Y^c\rangle$?

Comment: No problem! Take any element $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $\|x\| = 1$ and let $X = Y = \{x\}$. It can be easily checked that $\langle X, Y\rangle = 1$. But as $x\neq -x$ because $x\neq 0$ (because $\|x\| = 1$), $-x\not\in X$ and so $1 = \langle -x, -x\rangle \in \langle X^{c}, \mathbb{R}^{n}\rangle$. So $1\not\in \langle X, Y\rangle^{c}$ while $1\in \langle X^{c}, \mathbb{R}^{n}\rangle \cup \langle \mathbb{R}^{n}, Y^{c}\rangle$.

I will type the rest of the information up in an answer.

Comment: A very clean counter example, indeed. Thank you again. This is where I messed up. This argument would have worked for the Cartesian product because $\langle x,x\rangle \neq \langle -x,-x\rangle$ but not for inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the approach for showing that the set is bounded is correct, the approach for showing that the set is closed does not work because it is not true in general that $\langle X, Y\rangle^{c} = \langle X^{c}, \mathbb{R}^{n}\rangle \cup \langle \mathbb{R}^{n}, Y^{c}\rangle$.

One approach to prove the statement is to keep your proof of showing that $\langle X, Y\rangle$ is bounded and to show that the set is closed, you can use is to use sequences. You can take a convergent sequence in $\langle X, Y\rangle$ and show that the limit is also in $\langle X, Y\rangle$. This shows that $\langle X, Y\rangle$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Another approach suggested in the comments is to use that as $X$ and $Y$ are compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $X\times Y$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then show that the function $\phi :\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi (x,y) := \langle x, y\rangle$ is continuous. Then using that the image of a compact subset under a continuous function is again compact, it follows that $\phi (X\times Y) = \langle X, Y\rangle$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

One more approach is to use that subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are compact if and only if they are sequentially compact, which means that every sequence has a convergent subsequence. A sequence in $\langle X, Y\rangle$ is of the form $(\langle x_{n}, y_{n}\rangle )_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $x_{n}\in X$ and $y_{n}\in Y$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now you can use that $X$ and $Y$ are both sequentially compact to extract convergent subsequences, and extend this argument further so that a subsequence of $(\langle x_{n}, y_{n}\rangle )_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges.

Comment: I know I struggle to prove this but, if I follow the steps you suggested, I should be able to prove it? So at least the statement is true?

Comment: @curiosity Yes, the statements are true. If you have any questions about any steps or want to show what you have so far for some more advice, you are welcome to show that and I will help with that.

Comment: I could not thank you enough. Let me try myself for a little while and I will reach out to you if I get stuck. You have been so kind and helpful.